# Why .htaccess is calling index.php instead of search.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a small eCommerce website. I am replacing query string operators `?` and `&` with forward-slash `(/)`.

The directory is `www.somewebsite.com/product/`

Inside this directory, I have `index.php`, `search.php`, and `.htaccess` file.

And their query string parameters are `index.php?product_name=TheNameOfTheProduct` and `search.php?product_name=TheNameOfTheProduct&product_type=TheTypeOfTheProduct`

Now if I call `www.somewebsite.com/product/TheNameOfTheProduct` it works perfectly and gives me the product by calling the `index.php?product_name=TheNameOfTheProduct` internally. But if I call `www.somewebsite.com/product/search/TheNameOfTheProduct/TheTypeOfTheProduct` it still calls the `index.php?product_name=TheNameOfTheProduct` with the query string parameter `product_name` value as `search/TheNameOfTheProduct/TheTypeOfTheProduct`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file structure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?product_name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?product_name=$2&product_type=$3
```

And if I remove the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?product_name=$1` it starts working. But if I keep this line it does not work.

**Expectation Examples**

What I expect to call `index.php` if the URL is:

```
www.somewebsite.com/product/football
```

And to call `search.php` if the URL is:

```
www.somewebsite.com/product/football/8
```

How to set the `.htaccess` query string structure for each page separately, I mean dedicated `.htaccess` statements for each page URL? For example for `index.php` separate and for `search.php` separate in `.htaccess` file. Thanks!!!

Comment: And why does the least specific rule precede the search rule in that .htaccess?

Comment: Sir, I am very beginner in the world of `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need the search rule before the index rule to do what you want. Also read up on flags. You want to stop processing subsequent rules using the [L] flag.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ search.php?product_name=$2&product_type=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?product_name=$1
```

Comment: Sir, I am very beginner in the world of `.htaccess` files.

Comment: That's ok, but it may require some reading on your part. I showed an example. I would read the flags document though.

Comment: Thank you for your time but it didn't work. And if I remove the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?product_name=$1` it starts working. Do you have any idea what we are missing?

Comment: See the blue box at the top of your post with many other posts about solutions. I'm more familiar with IIS than htaccess.

Comment: Anyways Thanks!!!

Comment: The two `RewriteCond` directives go _with_ the "generic" rule you moved to the end, so these need to be moved with it as well. As it stands it will trigger a rewrite loop (500 response) since the directive runs unconditionally.